# Discord.js DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a Discord bot and there is a problem with the command named privacy policy in this bot, I asked a lot of people and they said they don't know.

Node.js version: 16.13.2
Discord.js version: 13.6.0

> **MAİN**

```js
client.commands = new Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

> **COMMAND**

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'gizlilik',
    description: 'gizlilik politikası',
    execute(message, args) {
    const Discord = require("discord.js")
    const gizlilik = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Hextro Gizlilik Politikası")
    .setDescription("Gizlilik Politikasına aşağıdaki butondan ulaşabilirsiniz.")
    .setColor("RANDOM")

    const buton = new Discord.MessageButton()
    .setLabel("Politika")
    .setStyle("url")
    .setURL("https://github.com/Husum0/Hextro-Gizlilik-Politikasi/blob/main/gizlilik.md");
    let row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(buton)
  
  message.channel.send({ content: 'Pong!', embeds: [gizlilik], components: [row] });
    },
};
```

> **ERROR**

Unhandled promise rejection: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
components[0].components[0].style: This field is required
at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\hexiye\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\hexiye\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\hexiye\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
method: 'post',
path: '/channels/931267478292680769/messages',
code: 50035,
httpStatus: 400,
requestData: {
json: {
content: 'Pong!',
tts: false,
nonce: undefined,
embeds: [Array],
components: [Array],
username: undefined,
avatar_url: undefined,
allowed_mentions: undefined,
flags: undefined,
message_reference: undefined,
attachments: undefined,
sticker_ids: undefined
},
files: []
}
}

Answer (score 0):

`url` is not a valid style to set your button to, instead, it should be `LINK` - see discord.js documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/typedef/MessageButtonStyle).

your command should end up looking like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'gizlilik',
    description: 'gizlilik politikası',
    execute(message, args) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const gizlilik = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Hextro Gizlilik Politikası')
            .setDescription('Gizlilik Politikasına aşağıdaki butondan ulaşabilirsiniz.')
            .setColor('RANDOM');

        const buton = new Discord.MessageButton()
            .setLabel('Politika')
            .setStyle('LINK')
            .setURL('https://github.com/Husum0/Hextro-Gizlilik-Politikasi/blob/main/gizlilik.md');
        let row = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(buton);

        message.channel.send({ content: 'Pong!', embeds: [gizlilik], components: [row] });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {ButtonStyle} from 'discord.js' //You need to import this enum from discord.js package

module.exports = {
    name: 'gizlilik',
    description: 'gizlilik politikası',
    execute(message, args) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const gizlilik = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Hextro Gizlilik Politikası')
            .setDescription('Gizlilik Politikasına aşağıdaki butondan ulaşabilirsiniz.')
            .setColor('RANDOM');

        const buton = new Discord.MessageButton()
            .setLabel('Politika')
            .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Link) // This gives link style to the button
            .setURL('https://github.com/Husum0/Hextro-Gizlilik-Politikasi/blob/main/gizlilik.md');
        let row = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(buton);

        message.channel.send({ content: 'Pong!', embeds: [gizlilik], components: [row] });
    }
};
```

`.setStyle("LINK")` I am not sure about this

Answer (score -6):

For when it says you have invalid for of body ,,, all that means is to update your app
Go to you appstore look for discord and update the app!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).